# How much space needed for a R matrix cell with 0 value? And how to deal with big matrix calculation

Tags: r, multithreading, matrix, memory-management, sparse-matrix

I want to calculate the correlation for a matrix, but stopped by program since the memory is not able to fit.

```
M = matrix(0, length(user), length(mat))
```

when I run this line,I got a message

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 146487.5 Gb

FYI

```
length(user) = 6728367
length(mat) = 2922138
```

so how much space a 0 value matrix cell need to occupy?

And further more, how to deal with the matrix calculation based on the sparse matrix? Is there a package? or I can do a multiple core calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much space is needed is mentioned in your error message: 146,487.5 GBs.

If you want such a big matrix, just use a sparse matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
user = 6728367
mat = 2922138
M = Matrix(0, user, mat)
```

This will work:

```
> str(M)
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int(0) 
  ..@ p       : int [1:2922139] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 6728367 2922138
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num(0) 
  ..@ factors : list()
```

There is a tutorial [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/vignettes/Introduction.pdf) and you can find a lot more online. Mathematical calculations are optimised with the package, so something like M * M will work fast as well.
Also, you can check [here](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/10/31/using-sparse-matrices-in-r/)

Comment: Thanks, this newly constructed Matrix can use some existing method like colSums, crossprod and even using  M[c(1,2)] = 0 to assign value to it, which make it very convenient

Comment: No problem. It is a very convenient package for sparse matrices. It has been around for a long time and is very well maintained.

Comment: By the way, do you know the method to turn a numeric data.frame to this type of Matrix? which means the method correspond to as.matrix() for normal matrix

Comment: one way is:  `as(as.matrix(df_here), 'sparseMatrix')`.

Comment: This not working for very large data.frame, since as.matrix will throw error for big matrix, I need to construct the sparse matrix using specific row index, col index and value instead, I think that is another interesting topic and must have some elegant solution, but so far my original correlation calculation problem is fully resolved in 1 min cost. I will accept your answer as the right one, and thank you one more time.

Comment: Happy to have helped :). Feel free to post another question about this and I think the community will help. It is an interesting topic